# Downloading binary data generated by a pyscript script

Tags: python, download, blob, gzip, pyscript

I need to download a binary file that is created by a pyscript script.

Pressing the "Download" button should result in downloading a file containing the binary data generated by the pyscript. However the result is a plaintext .txt file , with a single line inside it:

```
<gzip _io.BufferedWriter name='file_test.dat' 0xdce348>
```

Here's the code I use to create the "Download" button (the code is inside an async python function that is
called after a "start the program" button is clicked)

```
f_in = open('datafile','rb') // the file is opened. The file itself is stored in /home/pyodide/

//the contents of the file are written into a gzip.GzipFile 
f = open('file_test.dat','wb') 
gz = gzip.GzipFile('', 'wb', 8, f, 0.)

for ln in f_in:
  gz.write(ln)
  print(ln) // printing the file contents line by line results in correct data, so Im fairly certain that 
// the script itself generates data properly



//a blob object is created that is then attached to a new <a> tag 
blob = Blob.new([gz], {type: "application/gzip"})

downloadDoc = document.createElement('a')
downloadDoc.href = window.URL.createObjectURL(blob)

//then the <a> tag is appended to a <div> inside the main html file, and a download button is created
downloadButton = document.createElement('button')
downloadButton.innerHTML = "Download"
 
downloadDoc.appendChild(downloadButton)
document.getElementById("download-div").appendChild(downloadDoc)
```

I'm fairly new to web development (in fact this is my first web project), so there may be some obvious
thing I'm missing.

Thanks in advance!

**UPDATE - SOLUTION**

Closing all the files and passing the 'file_test.dat' file
to the pyodide.to_js() function before creating a Blob solves the problem. Here's the complete working code:

```
f_in = open('datafile','rb') 


f = open('file_test.dat','wb') 
gz = gzip.GzipFile('', 'wb', 8, f, 0.)

for ln in f_in:
  gz.write(ln)


gz.close()
f_in.close()
f.close()

//reopening the file and then passing it into pyodide.to_js() function solved the issue
f2 = open('file_test.dat',"rb") 
content = to_js(f2.read())
blob = Blob.new([content], {type: ""})

downloadDoc = document.createElement('a')
downloadDoc.href = window.URL.createObjectURL(blob)


downloadButton = document.createElement('button')
downloadButton.innerHTML = "Download"
 
downloadDoc.appendChild(downloadButton)
document.getElementById("download-div").appendChild(downloadDoc)
```

Comment: I see `gz.write(ln)` but where did you invoke `gz` initially? You don't include that part of your code? Plus, it isn't in a `with` context manager? What is closing the writing of the gzip? That may have nothing to do with why you are seeing the Python, but passing an unclosed file object to `Blob.new()` is at odds with you saying you created a binary file. Wouldn't you need an `open()` in there again or at least pass the stream? Things along the line of  bottom [here](https://www.jhanley.com/blog/pyscript-javascript-and-python-interoperability/) or ...

Comment: <continued> or [under 'Working with Streams' here](http://pymotw.com/2/gzip/#working-with-streams).

Comment: The `gz` variable is initialized a line before `gz.write(ln)` . I edited the post to include it

Comment: Performing the `content = to_js()` function you linked to on the file and then passing that into the `Blob` solved the issue. Thanks!

Comment: Awesome! I don't know though if it's quite clear now though what was the fix vs the original situation that the title of the post references. To help others with the situation you had, you may want to move what you have as the big code block now to a separation section with a header for the section, something like `UPDATED: Expanded for comments and Fix with content = to_js(f2.read()) Added,` and put back the original block in the original place. (You can add two asterisks both in front & at the end of the header to make it bold. Or add like three `#` in front of the text.)

Comment: I split the solution code from the original code. Thanks again for the anwser!